# Have trouble with the scope of a variable (Python / Pygame) without classes

Tags: python, scope

I create a variable on my `globals.py`, make some modification to it on a function named generatePlaylist and try to use her on another function.

1. `globals.py`

```py
import pygame as Py

selectedSong = None
```

2. function `generatePlaylist` and selection on `playlist.py`

```py
from globals import *
import os

songs = os.listdir('./assets/songs')  

def generatePlaylist(font, event):
    for index, song in enumerate(songs):
        rectIndex = Py.Rect(20, 25 + (50 * (index + 1)), 260, 40)
        rectIndexPosition = (20, 25 + (50 * (index + 1)))
        rectIndexWidth = 260
        rectIndexHeight = 40
        Py.draw.rect(screen, 'gray', rectIndex)
        text_surface = font.render(song, True, (0, 0, 0))
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=rectIndex.center)
        screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

        selected = selection(event, rectIndexPosition, rectIndexWidth, rectIndexHeight, song)
        if selected is not None:
            selectedSong = selected
            print(selectedSong)

        if index == len(songs) - 1:
            text_surface = font.render(song, True, (0, 0, 0))
            text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=rectIndex.center)
            screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
            rectDownload = Py.Rect(20, 25 + (50 * (index + 2)), 260, 40)
            Py.draw.rect(screen, 'gray', rectDownload)
            text_surface = font.render("Download", True, (0, 0, 0))
            text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=rectDownload.center)
            screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

def selection(event, rectIndexPosition, rectIndexWidth, rectIndexHeight, song):
    if event.type == Py.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if rectIndexPosition[0] <= event.pos[0] <= rectIndexPosition[0] + rectIndexWidth and \
               rectIndexPosition[1] <= event.pos[1] <= rectIndexPosition[1] + rectIndexHeight:
                return(song)
    return None
```

My print here says that `selectedSong` has been updated when I click.

3. My `main.py`

```py
import pygame as Py
from render import *
from buttonMusic import *
from playlist import *
from globals import *

Py.init()

continuer = True
script_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\Anthony\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\playerMusic\\assets"))
font_path = os.path.join(script_folder, 'assets', 'font', 'Roboto-Black.ttf')
font = Py.font.Font(font_path, 18)

while continuer:
    render(font)
    for event in Py.event.get():
        if event.type == Py.QUIT:
            continuer = False
        generatePlaylist(font, event)
        reculeButton(event)
        randomButton(event)
        playButton(event)
        pauseButton(event)
        stopButton(event)
        advanceButton(event)
        loopButton(event)
        upButton(event)
        downButton(event)
        muteButton(event)
Py.quit()
```

after generatePlaylist it's calling playButton

4. playButton on buttonMusic.py

```
from musicFunction import *
from globals import *

def playButton(event):
   if event.type == Py.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      if imagePlayPosition[0] <= event.pos[0] <= imagePlayPosition[0] + imagePlay.get_width() and \
         imagePlayPosition[1] <= event.pos[1] <= imagePlayPosition[1] + imagePlay.get_height():
         print(selectedSong)
         if selectedSong is not None:
            play()
```

Here my print stays again and again on `None` when I click.
5) Not sure you need it but my function `play` on `musicFunction.py`.

```py
def play():
    mx.music.load(f'./assets/songs/{selectedSong}')
    mx.music.play()
```

If you need it I can give you my GitHub repo thanks for the time you're giving to solve my problem.

Oh a new space to explain my problem, I try many things. Hard to explain what like change my variable from global to a function argument and many many things. What I expected just to find someone who can explain me why it's not working.

Comment: Foul language isn't necessary

Comment: Yeah my bad it wasn't the neaning but i have edit my post

Comment: To be cynical, I can say that, as a programmer, you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: every file runs `from globals import *` so it load old version - and it create own variables in own scope. I would rather create `selectedSong` in one file and in others I would send as parameter in functions (if it possible). ie. `def play(selectedSong):`

Comment: BTW: pygame has `pygame.Rect` to keep positon and size, and it has special functions to check collision with point (ie, mouse)- so you could check mouse click on button using simple `rectIndex.collidepoint(even.pos)` and it doesn't need `rectIndexPosition`, `rectIndexWidth` because you have `rectIndex.topleft` and `rectIndex.width`. And instead of `rectIndexPosition[0] + rectIndexWidth` you can use `rectIndex.right`

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is in this line:

`from globals import *`

This is telling python to give each of your modules their own copy of, in this case: `selectedSong = None`

Each module then proceeds to modify its own variable.

You should read this [blog entry](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder.

As a quick fix, I could suggest this:

1. globals.py

```py
selectedSong = None
```

then, just as an example of the other changes needed:

2. function generatePlaylist and selection on playlist.py

```py
import globals
import os

songs = os.listdir('./assets/songs')  

def generatePlaylist(font, event):
    for index, song in enumerate(songs):
        rectIndex = Py.Rect(20, 25 + (50 * (index + 1)), 260, 40)
        rectIndexPosition = (20, 25 + (50 * (index + 1)))
        rectIndexWidth = 260
        rectIndexHeight = 40
        Py.draw.rect(screen, 'gray', rectIndex)
        text_surface = font.render(song, True, (0, 0, 0))
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=rectIndex.center)
        screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

        selected = selection(event, rectIndexPosition, rectIndexWidth, rectIndexHeight, song)
        if selected is not None:
            globals.selectedSong = selected
            print(globals.selectedSong)
    ...
```

Using the form: `globals.selectedSong`, you then first refer to the module `globals` and then to the variable(s) inside that module. Now every module that refers to `globals` in this way, will refer to the *same* instance of `selectedSong`.

Comment: I would shy away from saying "copy"; rather, `from globals import *` defines new module globals that are *initialized* using the values of the variables defined in `globals`.

Comment: Yes, *copy* is difficult in `python`, but the names of the variables are being copied.

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code, but I think I can see the core of your problem.

1. In Python, "global variables" are actually only visible within the file they're created. However, it *is* possible have variables in different files that all point to the same object.
2. `import` statements create variables, just like an assignment statement.
3. `import globals` creates a variable called `globals` and assigns the module created from the file `globals.py`. Note the module is created only once, so you can see the same module from any file that has that same import statement. Globals from the file become attributes on the module object.
4. `from globals import *` takes the globals from `globals.py` and makes variables for them in the current file. It does not give you access to the module object. Assigning to one of those variables doesn't affect the module.

So you need to do `import globals` and  modify the module with `globals.selectedSong = selected` to make the change visible in other files.

In general, `from x import *` makes things very difficult, because you can't see where the variables in your code are being declared, so it's almost impossible to see what your code is doing in a program of any complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you feedback i keep your answer on a little part of my head... (so here) and give you one other answer that one of friend passing by find:

for the globals part

```
selectedSong = None
def set_selected_song(song):
    global selectedSong
    selectedSong = song

def get_selected_song():
    global selectedSong
    return selectedSong
```

for the playlist part

```
selected = selection(event, rectIndexPosition, rectIndexWidth, rectIndexHeight, song)
        if selected is not None:
            selectedSong = selected
            set_selected_song(selectedSong)
```

for the button part

```
def playButton(event):
   if event.type == Py.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      if imagePlayPosition[0] <= event.pos[0] <= imagePlayPosition[0] + imagePlay.get_width() and \
         imagePlayPosition[1] <= event.pos[1] <= imagePlayPosition[1] + imagePlay.get_height():
         selectedSong = get_selected_song()
         print(selectedSong)
         if selectedSong is not None:
            play()
```

and for the play part

```
def play():
    mx.music.load(f'./assets/songs/{get_selected_song()}')
    mx.music.play()
```